# Searching customfield after a field name

Tags: python, jira

I would like to search a customfield and it's ID, after a field name.
In Jira there can be some customfields and every has a name, which can't be seen in a log file.
For example I have the name: Markets, and I want to search which customfield (customfield_xxxxx) refers to this name.

Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: post a sample file, what you have tried..and have u tried using regex ?

Comment: I haven't tried, because I am still new to Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Custom Fields screen. Then go to the Market custom field and click in the Configure option in the right. You will navigate to a screen with this kind of url

```
http://localhost:8080/jira/secure/admin/ConfigureCustomField!default.jspa?customFieldId=10406
```

The custom field id is in this case `customfield_10406`.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the custom field id and match it with custom field name you can use [fields REST endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#api-api-3-field-get). It returns all custom and system fields (the custom field can be recognized by "custom" property). An example response from the endpoint is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "description",
    "name": "Description",
    "custom": false,
    "orderable": true,
    "navigable": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "clauseNames": [
      "description"
    ],
    "schema": {
      "type": "string",
      "system": "description"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "summary",
    "key": "summary",
    "name": "Summary",
    "custom": false,
    "orderable": true,
    "navigable": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "clauseNames": [
      "summary"
    ],
    "schema": {
      "type": "string",
      "system": "summary"
    }
  }
]
```